# If $1^3 = 1^2$, and take the$\ log_1$ on both sides, $3 = 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $$\boxed{1^3=1^2}$$ and I take the $$\log_1$$ on both sides, $$ 3=2,\ \quad ?$$

Comment: $log_{1} \left( \cdot \right)$ is undefined

Comment: um no. log_1 1 is technically undefined cuz it can take on multiple values. therefore u will get undefined values on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Logarithms do not use $  \ 1 \ $ as a base, since _all_ powers of $ \ 1 \ $ equal $ \ 1 \ $ .  There would be no difference between $ \ \log_1 \ 1^2 \ $ and $ \ \log_1 \ 1^3 \ $ and no way to express the logarithm of any positive number that _isn't_ $ \ 1  \ $ .

Comment: Ain't no such thing as $\log_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, $1^2=1^3$ does hold true but if you take the log of both the sides, you get $$2\log(1)=3\log(1)$$now, $\log(1)$ is equal to $0$ for any base except 1, and log base 1 is not defined, so you can't cancel the log from both the sides as that would be the same as dividing $0$ by $0$ which you can't do, that is why what you said does not hold true

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as $\log_1$.

And there's no such thing as $\log_0$ or $\log_{b}$ if $b < 0$.

The *definition* of $\log_b m = k\iff b^k = m$ relies upon the *assumption* that $b^k = b^j \iff k = j$ (and that for any $m > 0$ that there *is* a $k$ [and *only* on $k$] where $b^k =m$).

As this assumption is *not* true for $b = 0, 1$ or $b < 0$ we simply do not *have* any such $\log_1, \log_0$ or $\log_{b;b< 0}$

...

Also not if $m \ne 1$ the $\log_1 m $ makes no sense as we can *never* have $1^k = m$.  And $\log_1 1$ makes no sense because $1^k = 1$ for *ALL* $k$.  So $\log_1$ just makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Or more straightforward

$$\log_1{1}=\dfrac {\ln 1}{\ln 1}=\dfrac {0}{0}=\text{undefined}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no $\log_1$ function and, if any function were defined with such name, it would not satisfy $\log_1(1^a)=a$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\log_b(x)$ is only defined for $x,b \in \mathbb{R} :b>0, b\neq 1, x>0$

**Note**: Please look up Wikipedia (or other online sources that have already answered your question) before asking questions here.